# Select by category and order by custom field

Tags: php, wordpress, select, categories

Now I'm getting all post by category: "talleres". I'm using a plugin called "Custom Field" that leave me add more information to post that I'm editing. I want to select all post that are in "talleres" category and order by one of field (date_entry) of this meta post.

For example. We are going to imagine that we have two post in category "talleres":

- Taller 1
- Taller 2
- Taller 3

In the postmeta, this post have the following meta:

- Taller 1 -> date_entry (Field): 5/1/2017
- Taller 2 -> date_entry (Field): 7/1/2017
- Taller 3 -> date_entry (Field): 1/1/2017

The result, with the PHP query, could be:

```
Taller 3 with 1/1/2017
Taller 1 with 5/1/2017
Taller 2 with 7/1/2017
```

(Pay attention: ORDER BY date_entry). How I can do this query?

Comment: WP Query contains orderby parameter and you can use "meta_value" More here:https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

But I think that date you mentioned is in wrong format for compare as number, alphabetic or date. So seems like you have to get all posts in category, do some custom sorting throught object/array and print afterwards.

Comment: @Ángel please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/316137/1033581